TFT display driving
I want to make a 5 inch x 5 inch TFT display for outdoor/indoor purposes on which I can show videos with good clarity. It is for a consumer product so the cost cannot be more. I have gone through different methods through which I can drive the display (HDMI, 24-bit parallel interface, I2C).
Out of these interfacing methods which one should I choose? Are there any developer boards which I should buy?
Any help is appreciated.

For outdoor use in daylight, special extra bright displays are usually required. Those interfaces all have strong pros and cons. Your question is too vague to discuss that though without writing a novel about it. Yes, buy a dev kit. That will get you started.

cost cannot be more ... more than what? ... did you mean cost cannot be high?

WHY THE SHOUTING?

TFT displays use a backlight, and an LCD panel that blocks some of the light.   There are a few tricks that can help (like, a mesh on the display face that absorbs most incident light but has good transparency on-axis of the display) but basically you will need a very bright backlight for
the display, if it is to be legible in sun.
You might also want the user to be wearing black; there is always a bit
of reflection at a display's surface, and the straight-on viewer will see
his own reflection.
So-called antireflection surface coatings are possible, as are 'privacy screen' items (that, like a black mesh, block much off-axis ambient light).  They're widely available, but maybe not in your 5x5 size.
The most convenient interface might be USB-C; the connectors are small, the wiring well-supported, and it can be a power as well as signal link.

If you want to show video, definitely can not use I2C or SPI. Those band width is not big enough.
RGB, LVDS, HDMI, VGA are good choices. USB-C and DP of course can do it too. But not sure if you can find suitable dev board.
